# How to edit a formula on existing formula for all cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to add an IF Statement on a VLOOKUP that is referencing different cells based on another worksheets. How can Simultaneously add an IF Statement for all cells without changing the VLOOKUP References? I tried Recording a macro on the first cells but it just does not work as it copies the VLOOKUP Referencing from the first cell.
Hi There,

For example, The Current Table:

| State | Values |
| --- | --- |
| England | VLOOKUP(reference1) |
| Wales | VLOOKUP(reference2) |
| England | VLOOKUP(reference3) |
| Wales | VLOOKUP(reference4) |

Answer (score 1):

I do this often by replacing "=VL" with "xyxyxy" with turns all the formulae into text using find/replace.

Then I use find/replace to insert the extra text, an example: replace "UP(r" with "UP(if(reference=1,1,0)" etc

Then I reverse the "xyxyxy" and replace with "=VL" which reinstates the formulae to working.

Fine tune as you need.

**And make sure you work on a copy**